# Capistrano Multiple Servers: How to refer to current server during deploy?

Tags: capistrano

Some background, I am capistrino running 2.9.0 and capistrano-ext 1.2.1.  Multistage deployment is working as expected.  As is adding arrays of server to the roles.

```
INSTANCES = ["this.server.com", "that.server.com"]
role(:web) {INSTANCES}
```

I've been trying to make :deploy_to produced a path based on the name of the server being deployed, like so:

```
set :deploy_to, lambda { "/var/www/application/$HOSTNAME" }
```

This is working pretty well, except this.server.com and that.server.com are actually the same host.  In this example, instead of having two deploy folders based off the server names defined in my deploy/stage.rb file, it just produces the one /var/www/application/server.com/

I've been digging around looking for a way to either inject this at the capistrano level or reference a shell variable that would retain these details.  It seems like needing to host an application server with multiple instances of an app would be common.

What I really need is:

```
set :deploy_to, lambda { "/var/www/application/$SERVER_NAME_CAP_IS_USING" }
```

Comment: I don't think using different usernames will work here either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://railsware.com/blog/2011/11/02/advanced-server-definitions-in-capistrano/) helps. You can define specific ServerDefinition objects and call to those per task or whatever:

```
set(:boss_host, {
  Capistrano::ServerDefinition.new('boss.reservoir.dogs', {
    :user => 'boss',
    :port => 2222,
    :ssh_options => {
      :keys => './keys/boss.pem'
    }
})

run("date", :hosts => [ :boss_host ]
```